# Centering Input Form inside a Grid Table [BOOTSTRAP 3]

Tags: html, forms, grid, centering

So, I'm working on  a responsive site. And, I can't manage to center an input box inside a div. The input form keeps shifting down, and is invisible.

I need a way that I could center the input box inside the blue section of the code, and actually make it visible.

HERE'S THE LINK TO THE CURRENT PROJECT [click here](http://test-borismediaprods.c9users.io/index.html)

Here's my HTML File:

```css
.my_logo {
    margin: 0;
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
}

html,body {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  height:100%;
  min-height:100%;
 }

.quarter{
  width:100%;
  height:50%;
}

.contents{
  height:50%;
  width:100%;
}

body {
  padding-top: 60px;
}

button, #input{
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.quarter:before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>


<html>
    <head>
        <title>BusBuzz BETA</title>
        <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="custom/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class = "navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <center>
                    <img src="img/temp_logo.png" style="height: 60px;">
                </center>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="contents">
        <div class="col-md-6 quarter text-center" style="background-color:blue;">
            <a class="btn btn-danger btn-responsive" style="top: 50%;" href="#">Set Up Geolocation!</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 quarter text-center" style="background-color:red;">
   <!--PROBLEM-->         <input type="text" class="form-control"></input>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 quarter" style="background-color:yellow;"></div>
        <div class="col-md-6 quarter text-center" style="background-color:green;">
             <a class="btn btn-danger btn-responsive" style="top: 50%;" href="#">Set Alarm!</a>    
        </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that you meant centering the input box in the red  since that's what your code is showing.  Based on this, are you certain that the class "text-center" does something?  I know it does something in Bootstrap, but your code is correct as far as Bootstrap goes.  Do you have a link to this live somewhere?

Comment: @BorisMediaProds - What are you using the .quarter class for?  It looks like you're creating your own custom rules that are conflicting with Bootstraps rules.

Comment: I've used the quarter class to essentially split the screen in 4 sections, as I'm trying to fit 4 different buttons/forms inside the 4 sections. That's why I have the 4 ugly colours to help me identify that the sections are evenly split.

Comment: @BorisMediaProds - Ok, then you either need to use your quarter class or use the Bootstrap col-md-6 classes.  You can't use both.  Your quarter class height is what's causing the form to fall outside of the div (thus making it invisible).  Just to verify, remove the "height" attribute on .quarter and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Thanks Derik, love you. But how can I use the bootstrap class to fill up the screen in 4 parts.

Comment: @BorisMediaProds - You can't.  Bootstrap is for setting up a responsive grid.  You can set each div to col-md-6, but then their heights won't match.  If you're just trying to use quarters, I wouldn't even use Bootstrap.

Comment: so there's no way I could use bootstrap to make a responsive grid of 4 rows?

Comment: Not really the way you're trying to do it.  Here's a fiddle that uses your existing code and just removes the Bootstrap classes along with your .quarter:before rules.

https://jsfiddle.net/vL79tk9y/

**Edit**: I should clarify that it's not that you *can't* do this in Bootstrap, it's just that it's unnecessary and would require Javascript.